# Avoid bubbling in the nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

I have this html code:

```
<td class="myclass">
    <span>
        <span>xxxx</span>
    </span>
    <span>xxxx</span>
    <span>xxxx</span>
</td>
```

I'm attaching the click event to the elements with class "myclass" passing a fuction as callback. In that function I receive in event.target anyone of the elements but the element that I want to get is the td. ¿Can I avoid the bubbling in order to get always the td in the target or the event?

Big thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`this`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) context inside `handler-function`

```js
$('.myclass').on('click', function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="myclass">
      <span>
        <span>xxxx</span>
      </span>
      <span>xxxx</span>
      <span>xxxx</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Or** [***`e.currentTarget`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

> *Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element the event handler has been attached to as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the event occurred.*

```js
$('.myclass').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="myclass">
      <span>
        <span>xxxx</span>
      </span>
      <span>xxxx</span>
      <span>xxxx</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I forget to let know that I cannot use this because I need to attach the events this way:    $('.myclass').on('click',myFunction); Once in my function "this"  is the document.

Comment: @MKP – How about the second approach ?

Comment: "this" or "e.currentTarget" are the document itself in the callback function. Thx for your help.